# How "Optimal" are Solutions from Gradient Descent?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

When optimizing the Loss Functions of Neural Networks using (some version of the) Gradient Descent algorithm, I have often heard this situation described as a Sequential Optimization Problem. This means that because it is usually impossible (i.e. too computationally expensive) to optimize the Loss Function by jointly solving a system of Non-Linear equations, we have to "sequentially" find better and better solutions to this problem until some criteria is met (e.g. error threshold, number of iterations).

I am interested in knowing if this type of optimization problem (i.e. Sequential Optimization of Loss Functions) has ever been studied through the lens of Bellman Optimality. **For instance, do we have any reasons to believe that such optimization problems might have "Optimal Substructure and Overlapping Subproblems"?**

I am interested in knowing about this for the following reason: **Do we have any theoretical reasons to believe that sequential optimization of Loss Functions has any "chance" at finding some type of Optimal Solution - or do we just assume this is true and hope for the best (i.e. a "good enough solution")?**

- Can sequentially solving these kinds of optimization problems theoretically lead to some optimal solution?

Thanks!